# Is There any sonar plugin that analyzes handlebar templates

Tags: sonarqube, handlebars.js

One of our projects uses handlebars.js and as far as I know sonarqube javascript (SonarJS) plugin does not support .hbs files. Is there any plugin for sonarqube that analyzes handlebars template files (*.hbs) ?

-thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no plugin supporting particularly `.hbs` files. While probably you could use SonarWeb plugin but it will not bring any issues specific to Handlebar templates.